# How to $broadcast function to other controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-treeview

I have three screens each screen have same functionality for location treeview dropdown I implemented below function and now i want to use this across application wherever we need location treeview dropdown.Lets say i have another controller Ctrl2.js how i can use updateGeolocationList() function from Ctrl1.js.Any help will be appreciated.

Ctrl1.js

```
$scope.updateGeoLoctionList = function(geoLocation){
        var pos = $.inArray(geoLocation.text, selectedGeoLocations);

        if(pos < 0){
            selectedGeoLocations.push(geoLocation.text);
            selectedGeoLocationIds.push(geoLocation.id);
            //if Global is checked disable all parent and children
            if (geoLocation.id === 5657){
              $.each(geoLocation.parent(),function(index,location) {
                if (location.id !== geoLocation.id) {
                  $.each(location._childrenOptions.data.items,function(index,child){
                    var disableChildId = 'disabled' + child.id;
                    var model = $parse(disableChildId);
                      model.assign($scope, true);
                  })
                  var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
                  // Get the model
                  var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                  // Assigns a value to it
                  model.assign($scope, true);

                }
              });
            }
}
```

Config.js

```
geoLocationTreeConfig : {
        template: '{{dataItem.text}}',
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: false,
           template: '<input ng-disabled=\'disabled#: item.id #\' type=\'checkbox\' ng-click=\'updateGeoLoctionList(dataItem)\' value=\'true\' />'
        }
    },controlInPrcsGeoLocationTreeConfig : {
        template: '{{dataItem.text}}',
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: false,
            template: '<input  {{dataItem.disabled}} type=\'checkbox\' ng-click=\'populateControlInPrcsGeoLoction(dataItem)\' value=\'true\' />'
        }
    },riskInPrcsGeoLocationTreeConfig : {
        template: '{{dataItem.text}}',
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: false,
            template: '<input  ng-disabled=\'disabled#: item.id #\' type=\'checkbox\' ng-click=\'populateRisToProcesskGeoLoctionList(dataItem)\' value=\'true\' />'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use $broadcast or $emit (bubble up, vs down), but I think a better pattern is to move this into it's own directive. Then you can include that directive into any html that you want. Include a ng-click with that directive and whenever the user clicks that element the dropdown will appear.

But without more information/code it's hard to fully understand what your intent is as this is only a config object, and a function from a controller. But here's a link to the kindo tree view angular page for more info: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use `updateGeoLoctionList` in other application and directive the best solution would be to place it into a service. That service can then be injected into a directive, controller, or other service for use.